# Unexpected babel transform with invalid assignment

Tags: babeljs

I have ran into what I think is a bug with Babel, but want to make sure I am not accidentally stumbling on some sort of transform I don't know about.

Here is the [code](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20name%20%3D%20'sam'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20me%3A%20%7Bname%3A%20'sam'%7D%3B&playground=true)

[image]

I would expect this to be a syntax error, not an assignment of `me` to `void 0`. Is this a bug, or is there a reason behind this?

Comment: Screenshot of code is never a valid substitute for actual code.

Comment: @JanDvorak Apologies, link to the code added.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an assignment via colon `:`, which is invalid syntax.

The following works just fine:

```
let name = 'sam',
    me = {name: 'sam'};
```

Comment: I understand that it is invalid assignment syntax. My question is why doesn't  this fail with a syntax error when ran through babel.